Characterization of vectors at a given distance from the Reed-Solomon code
Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{F}$ with $|\Omega| = n > 0$ and $0 < k \leqslant n$.  Write
$$\epsilon: \mathbb{F}[X]^{<n} \to \mathbb{F}^\Omega, \qquad f \mapsto (f(\omega))_{\omega \in \Omega}$$
for the map sending a polynomial $f$ of degree $<n$ to its evaluations on $\Omega$.  Then $C = \epsilon(\mathbb{F}[X]^{<k})$ is a Reed-Solomon code of length $n$ and dimension $k$ over $\mathbb{F}$.  The distance of a $v \in \mathbb{F}^\Omega$ from $C$ is the minimum of the distance from $v$ to any codeword $u \in C$.  Denote this value $d(v, C)$.
The map $\epsilon$ is a bijection.  How can the $f \in \mathbb{F}[X]^{<n}$ such that $d(\epsilon f, C) = l$ be characterized (for some given $0 \leqslant l \leqslant n - k$)?

Related question from same user: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5009946/number-of-vectors-at-a-given-distance-from-a-reed-solomon-code
